# Extracting data from a dict like column in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have column `info` in a dataframe with data in dict like format like the one below.

I would like to get another dataframe with this info and a tried:

```
feature = [d.get('Feature') for d in df['info']]
```

but it returns none.

How can I do it?  I am really having a bad time trying to get this done.

Comment: It is  hard to understand without more information about what you are trying to do, the data and the dataframe. The dictionnary you gave us has at least 3 level of depth, which means it can not come from a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the dict is nested, you can try [`pd.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) which normalizes semi-structured JSON data into a flat table:

```
df_new = pd.json_normalize(df['info'])
```

As some inner dict are further under a list, you may need to further handle this to dig out the deeper contents.  Anyway, this should serve well as a starting point for your works.